# Qt - moc causing C2504: base class undefined

Tags: qt

I'm having a problem that I've been trying to solve for a while, but I am completely stumped.  So I have two classes, X and Y, and they each have their own header files, X.h and Y.h.  Each is a Q_OBJECT and has that macro definition in the header file.

```
class Y: public X { Q_OBJECT ...}
```

The definition of Y reads.  The definition of X reads:

```
class X: public QGLWidget {Q_OBJECT ...}
```

When I compile, X.cpp and Y.cpp compile correctly and there are no problems at that stage.  The moc files are also generated with no problem.

However, when the standard QT build process goes to compile moc_X.cpp, it gives me "C:\path\Y.h(34) : error C2504: 'X' : base class undefined".  But this doesn't happen when it's compiling Y.cpp or X.cpp, it only happens when it's compiling the moc files!  Any ideas?  That the build would be failing at the moc stage and only moc stage seems extremely peculiar.  Help is much appreciated!

Comment: By any change did you forward declare class X and didn't include the header?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've tried reproducing it, with the description you give, and haven't been able to.

So, here are things that would be worth checking:

**errors in include guards?**

Check that you haven't accidentally got 2 include-guards of the same name in 2 different headers (i.e. the `#ifndef X_H` and `#define X_H` lines)

(This is perhaps less likely, from your description: it would be more likely if the error was in the compiling of moc_Y.cpp)

**forward declarations for types used in signals or slots?**

Sometimes a parameter in a signal or slot can require an extra header to be included.

The best way I can explain it is to say that there are cases where your header would be fine with a forward-declaration to a class, but the `moc` can generate code that needs to actually create or destroy a type that your header only forward-declares.

If this is the case, there is a way to add code to the .ui, that requests inclusion of the extra header for the forward-declared type. But the easiest solution is just to replace the forward declaration with the appropriate header instead, inside X.h or Y.h.

**check the contents of the moc_X.cpp file**

If the above doesn't help, and if you haven't done so already, I'd suggest opening up the offending moc file and reading the code. Once you see what it's doing, it might give you some ideas.

Comment: When I read the moc file, it did seem that your second point "forward declarations for types used in signals or slots" might be the issue.  The #includes on my project were kind of badly structured anyway, and when I restructured them all, things compiled.  Thanks!