# Is Qt Creator built with Qt Creator?

Tags: qt, qt4

Questions:

1. Is Qt Creator built with Qt Creator?
2. Similarly, is Qt Designer built with Qt Designer?
3. BTW, why are there two Qt IDEs? Are they competitors? Which one should I use? I am using Creator.
4. What is Qt SDK? I am asking this because the Qt Designer & Creator 2.2.1 and Qtmake 4.7.4 that I installed thro ubuntu 11.10 s/w centre does not work. The build menu is all greyed out.
   When I downloaded the latest QtSDK (2.3.1/4.7.4) into a separate installation into /opt/QtSDK, both the ubuntu sanctioned installation and the /opt/QtSDK would work as expected.
   Why did my ubuntu sanctioned installation not work without the SDK? What does the SDK do?
5. This one is for Ubuntu enthusiasts - Qt IDE requires the SDK to work, and yet ubuntu released both Creator/Designer without checking if they work first? There is no QtSDK installation item in s/w centre. Is that intentional, or a procedural bug?
6. After I build my desktop app (I am building a tabbed file explorer) on Linux, what steps do I need to make to have it running on Windows 7/Vista? Will I rebuild on a windows version  of Qt Creator?

I also notice that Qt Creator code generation is not perfect. It would forget to include some Qt library files in the auto-generated code, and I had to correct that manually.

Comment: Qt Creator is an IDE, which includes Qt Designer, a layout builder.

Comment: Ya, Qt Creator can do layout design too. Why is there a separate qt designer? Is that necessary?

Comment: Having been a C++, Java and .NET programmer for too many years, I found Qt very intuitive.After, finally deciding may be I should install from Nokia download directly (which took 1.6GB ~2hours), it took me about 10 minutes to create a respectable app and putting in simple event handlers (slots?? What's that?). If you are used to event-driven or even mvp/mvc, and an experienced Java/.NET programmer and don't mind c++, you should give Qt4 a try.

Comment: ok, and what was the crux of the last comment with reference to your question ?

Comment: Blessed Geek: designer predates Qt Creator by a decade or so. Being available standalone, one can use designer without having to use Qt Creator.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### Is Qt Creator built with Qt Creator?

I believe so.

That doesn't mean that *everyone* who works on Qt has to use it - just that I believe that *lots* of people do.

I don't work for any of the companies that have produced Qt, but my reasoning is:

- A Google search for "dogfooding qt creator" brings up plenty of hits, including [this comment](http://blog.qt.nokia.com/2010/11/09/qt-4-7-1-and-qt-mobility-1-1-0-released/) from November 2010:

  > We’re also “dogfooding” by releasing complex apps like Qt Creator and the Ovi Suite on the desktop ports of Qt
- They've put a massive amount of effort into Qt Creator over the last few years. It's hard to imagine that being worthwhile, unless they used it themselves
- At recent Qt Developer Days, Qt Developers have spoken really enthusiastically about Qt Creator

#### Similarly, is Qt Designer built with Qt Designer?

Yes. A look at the Qt Designer source code shows plenty of .ui (Designer) files.

#### Why are there two Qt IDEs? Are they competitors? Which one should I use? I am using Creator.

When you edit .ui files insiide Qt Creator, you are still running Qt Designer: it's simply showing the Designer window inside Creator, for convenience.

#### What is Qt SDK? ... What does the SDK do?

[Qt SDK](http://qt.nokia.com/downloads/) is just a convenient way to download all the Qt tools in one go. You don't *have* to use it.

#### This one is for Ubuntu enthusiasts ... Is that intentional, or a procedural bug?

Sorry - no idea. It's hard to imagine it being intentional though.

#### After I build my desktop app (I am building a tabbed file explorer) on Linux, what steps do I need to make to have it running on Windows 7/Vista? Will I rebuild on a windows version of Qt Creator?

You will need to install Qt on a Windows PC, and then build your source code in it.

You can either do that by using Qt Creator and the Windows compiler it includes (mingw) or you can use another compiler, if you have one, e.g. Visual Studio.

#### I also notice that Qt Creator code generation is not perfect. It would forget to include some Qt library files in the auto-generated code, and I had to correct that manually.

If you've used any non-Qt classes in arguments to signals and slots, then [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7407792/qt-moc-causing-c2504-base-class-undefined/7408756#7408756) may help you there.

Comment: About Designer vs. Creator, my personal experience is that I can access more features in the Designer than in the form editor of Creator. Ressources handling is better in the designer. Sometime ago I gave Qwt a shot. Qwt widgets appeared in the designer but not in the form editor of creator. All in all, I use the form designer in the creator most of the time. But every now and then I have to fall back to the original designer for some missing feature.